# How to fix ORA-01722 invalid number

Tags: oracle, procedure

I want to run procedure but I see ORA-01722 problem how can i solve this problem?

```
create or replace 
PROCEDURE INSERTQUESTION(
       p_name IN QUESTION.NAME%TYPE,
       p_tag IN QUESTION.TAG%TYPE,
       p_money IN QUESTION.MONEY%TYPE,
       p_explain IN QUESTION.EXPLAIN%TYPE,
     p_img IN QUESTION.PHOTOID%TYPE,
     p_mail IN USERS.MAIL%TYPE)
IS
BEGIN

  INSERT INTO QUESTION ("NAME",
  "CREATEDATE",
  "TAG","STATUS",
  "MONEY","PHOTOID","OWNID","EXPLAIN") 
  VALUES (p_name,CURRENT_DATE,p_tag,'T',p_money,p_mail,(SELECT ID FROM USERS WHERE MAIL=p_mail),p_explain);

  COMMIT;

END;
```

This is my starting procedure comment:

```
begin
insertquestion('Debu','Connectionsss',32,'aeaea',125,'cerate');
end;
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include the definition of the `QUESTION` table, along with all of its fields. Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the _full_ error, and not just the error code? Any other useful details like _where_ the query failed?